# Notification addAction creates button with no behavior

Tags: android, android-intent, android-notifications

I am trying to add a button to my notification in android.
I use the `addAction` method in order to add an intent which supposes to open up the main activity (same as clicking the entire notification) but with an extra bundle with data.
this is what I have done so far:

```
notificationManager = (NotificationManager)this.getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

//regular intent to view main activity
PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this,Constants.MAIN_ACTIVITY,
                              new Intent(this, MainActivity.class), 0);

//intent for viewing transaction dialog, within main activity using PURCHASE_DIALOG request code
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putParcelableArrayList(Constants.LIST, (java.util.ArrayList<? extends android.os.Parcelable>) list);
PendingIntent purchaseIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
                               this, Constants.PURCHASE_DIALOG,
                               new Intent(this, MainActivity.class), 0, bundle);

NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                        .setContentTitle(Constants.NOTIFICATION_TOPIC)
                        .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle()
                        .bigText(watchResponse.toString()))
                        .setAutoCancel(true)
                        .addAction(R.drawable.ic_launcher, "Buy", purchaseIntent)
                        .setContentText(message);

mBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
notificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, mBuilder.build());
```

I simply expect that my `onResume` in `MainActivity` class will be called once clicking the extra action, and there i'll be able to get the bundle trough `getIntent()`, yet nothing happens when I click on it. the button is clicked, but the activity remains open and my application activity wont start.

Answer (score 0):

I had a very similar issue but a very different solution. Pending intent is also not fired if you have declared `<service android:enabled="false"></service>` in your manifest.xml file.

Replace from `android:enabled="false"` to `android:enabled="true"`

This might not be a direct issue of the problem. But if you create the service in android studio using default template it automatically adds these properties to the service.

If this does not work there is a similar question you can find here:
[Android Notification Action is not fired (PendingIntent)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14841740/android-notification-action-is-not-fired-pendingintent/34908977#34908977)